# Passando values de um Select Multiple para o banco (Codeigniter)

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, codeigniter, select

**Minha view está assim:**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="categorias[]">Selecione a(s) categoria(s) referente(s) a foto:</label>
    <select name="categorias[]" class="form-control" multiple="multiple" required>
        <?php foreach ($listarCategorias->result() as $row) : ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $row->idCategoria; ?>"><?php echo $row->dscCategoria; ?></option>
        <?php endforeach ?>
    </select>
</div>
```

**Como ficaria o código do meu controller/model para que os values desse select fossem registrados um em cada linha na minha tabela do banco?**

Comment: passa pra um json e armazena

Answer (score 2):

Uma possibilidade seria o seguinte dentro do seu **controller/model**:

```
$array['categorias'] = $this->input->post('categorias');
foreach ($array['categorias'] as $value) {
    echo $value;
}
```